# How do I make the “Text contains” evaluate any word written in the cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, regex, text-formatting

I just want the cell in Google Sheets to change its fill color when any text is inputted in the cell? But it has to be text excluding numbers. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1,"[0-9]")),1)*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

#### EU syntax:

```
=IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1;"[0-9]"));1)*(A1<>"")
```